# controller is not a function error with AngularJS 1.5.7

Tags: angularjs, controller

I've a very simple app with no code in it yet. I've removed it to check for this error that I am getting - "angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ClientFileConfigController' is not a function, got undefined"

I've followed the similar patter in my angularjs app (1.5.3) and it works fine. This code is using angularjs (1.5.7) and the only difference is I used bower to individually chose my packages, rather than using nuget.

I am unable to decode this error :-(

app.js

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('ConfigApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'TreeWidget']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        var viewBase = '/app/ConfigApp/views/';

        $routeProvider
            .when('/clients', {
                controller: 'ClientFileConfigController',
                templateUrl: viewBase + 'clients.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            //.when('/clients/:clientId/:fileId', {
            //    controller: 'clientfileEditController',
            //    templateUrl: viewBase + 'edit.html',
            //    controllerAs: 'vm'
            //})
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/clients' });

    }]);

}());
```

clientfileConfigController.js

```
(function(){
    var injectParams = ['$scope'];

    var ClientFileConfigController = function ($scope) {

    }

    ClientFileConfigController.$inject = injectParams;
    angular.module('ConfigApp').controller('ClientFileConfigController', ClientFileConfigController)
}());
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="ConfigApp">
<head>
    <title>Client File Angular Tree Widget</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/clients">Clients</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    .top-buffer { margin-top:20px; }
    <div class="slide-animation-container">
        <div ng-view id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

clients.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <!--<tree nodes='treeNodes'>-->
</body>
</html>
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhONB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error on two scenarios:

1. Controller not included in script. (undefined)
2. Injector dependency couldn't be resolved.

Comment: The only injector dependency here is $scope for the controller. With AngularJS already referenced, I don't see an issue with this. I've put the controller script as mentioned in my code.

Comment: Wat abt the IIFE as @ocespedes said, I dint notice it though

Comment: I might not have included the script file properly...let me review

Comment: Thank you...not linking the controller js file properly (typo) in my html is the main issue...so, your point 1 (controller not included in script is the correct hint)

Answer (score 1):

Change your IIFE to this structure:

```
(function (){
   //your code here
})()
```

and include your controller in the script

Comment: Isn't it the same way I used? 
(function(){
 //clientfileConfigController here
}());

Comment: @vrkala no...look at how you closed it and invoked it

Comment: I changed but no luck!

Comment: I observed something though...When I do F12 and go to "sources" in chrome, I don't see the controller js file...

Comment: @ocespedes On a different note, a quick question why IIFE needs to be defined the way you told...while it is working for me the way I defined?

Comment: You can have more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript about IIFE

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you need to include the js files in your index html page. Angular is looking for your controller but there is no file specified that contains the code for it